# Run Playwright scripts written in TypeScript with Artillery

Tags: playwright, artillery, playwright-typescript

We are trying to execute Playwright test scripts written in TypeScript in Artillery.
I want suggestions as I could find examples only with Playwright - JavaScript with Artillery.
I understand that TypeScript can be transpiled to JavaScript. However, we are facing issues in that as well.
So,

1. How do we run Playwright TS with Artillery?
2. Are there other options/tools/node modules to run Load Testing with TypeScript?

Any suggestions, or experience will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Artillery only supports javascript files. It would be grea to be able to create the javascript playwright scripts from the VSCode playwright extensions but it only creates the test scripts in typescript. You have to run codegen outside of VSCode to make the right selection of using the Javascript library.
I really like the automated way you can create assertions from the extension recording for the typescript functionality but oh well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).